# .htaccess for mod_rewrite for Amazon S3

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, amazon-s3

I did a few searches, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for, so apologies if someone asked this already.

I'm aware that .htaccess is an apache server feature, and not standard to S3 buckets. I'm hosting static html files on s3 bucket. I wanted to use .htaccess to mod_rewrite example.com/contact.html to example.com/contact

Also wanted to use .htaccess to force all http:// requests to SSL https://

Is there no way to achieve this using Amazon S3 Buckets?
If there is a way, please give detailed instructions so I don't get lost :P

THANK YOU!

Comment: do you have solution for this already?